# Access to a list in a parent class Python

Tags: python, class

I work on a Python code which requires a parent class "Equalizer" and a child class "lms". Here is the code:

```
class equalizer:
    """
    Class equalizer
    """
    step: []                        # Step
    step_min: float                 # Minimum step
    step_max: float                 # Maximum step
    _variable_step: bool            # Authorize variable step
    

    def __init__(self, number_of_taps, step, sample_rate, bit_rate, alphabet, variable_step):

        self.configure_step(step)
        self._variable_step = variable_step
      

    def configure_step(self, new_step=-1):
        """
        Update the step
        :param new_step:
        :return: None
        """

        if new_step > 0:
           self.step.append(new_step)

        else:
            raise Exception("StepValue: the step value has to be greater than 0.")
```

```
class lms(equalizer):

    def __init__(self, number_of_taps, step, sample_rate, bit_rate, alphabet, variable_step=True):
        super().__init__(number_of_taps, step, sample_rate, bit_rate, alphabet, variable_step)

        self.step_min = 0
        self.step_max = 1
```

Main file:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import equalizer.lms as eq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nrz_alphabet = np.array([-1, 1])
pam4_alphabet = np.array([-3, -1, 1, 3])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nrz_alphabet = np.array([-1, 1])
    pam4_alphabet = np.array([-3, -1, 1, 3])

    data = read_data(r"..\data\FIR_at_transmitter\NRZ_40_0_0_0_0_0.csv")

    lms_eq = eq.lms(number_of_taps=6, step=0.1,
                    sample_rate=100, bit_rate=25, alphabet=nrz_alphabet)
    lms_eq.lms(data)

    plt.show()
```

When I try to run it in the *main* file, I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\digitalEqualization\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    lms_eq = eq.lms(number_of_taps=6, step=0.1,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\digitalEqualization\equalizer\lms.py", line 9, in __init__
    super().__init__(number_of_taps, step, sample_rate, bit_rate, alphabet, variable_step)
  File "C:\digitalEqualization\equalizer\equalizer.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.configure_step(step)
  File "C:\digitalEqualization\equalizer\equalizer.py", line 72, in configure_step
    self.step.append(new_step)
    ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'lms' object has no attribute 'step'
```

I think this problem is a portability problem of my step variable between the parent class and the child class.

My variable *step* is a list of all step value that my object of my class lms will take.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You never initialized `self.step`. Maybe you wanted `step: list = []` in the class definition.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias, that was my problem! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to initialized the list:

Remplace:

```
step = []
```

By:

```
step: list = []
```

Comment: `step = []` would be fine. The problem is that your wrote `step: []`